# What is wrong with my proof!

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

Let $S=\{(\alpha,\beta)\in \mathbb R^2:\frac{x^\alpha y^\beta}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2} }\rightarrow0 $ as $(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)\}$ , then $S$ is contained in which of the following set?

$(1)$$A=\{(\alpha,\beta)\in \mathbb R^2:\alpha>0,\beta>0\} $

$(2)$$B=\{(\alpha,\beta)\in \mathbb R^2:\alpha>2,\beta>2\} $

$(3)$$C=\{(\alpha,\beta)\in \mathbb R^2:\alpha+\beta>1\} $

$(4)$$D=\{(\alpha,\beta)\in \mathbb R^2:\alpha+4\beta>1\} $

Solution

let $y=x$,then $\frac{x^\alpha y^\beta}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2} }\rightarrow0\implies$ $\frac{x^{\alpha+ \beta}}{\sqrt{x^2+x^2} }\rightarrow0$ $\implies$ $\frac{x^{\alpha+ \beta}}{x\sqrt{2} }\rightarrow0 \implies \frac{x^{\alpha+ \beta-1}}{\sqrt{2} }\rightarrow0\implies \alpha+\beta-1>0\implies\alpha+\beta>1$

Hence,option $C$ is correct.

let $y=x^4$,then $\frac{x^\alpha y^\beta}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2} }\rightarrow0\implies$ $\frac{x^{\alpha+ 4\beta}}{\sqrt{x^2+x^8} }\rightarrow0$ $\implies$ $\frac{x^{\alpha+ 4\beta}}{x\sqrt{1+x^6} }\rightarrow0 \implies \frac{x^{\alpha+ 4\beta-1}}{\sqrt{1+x^6} }\rightarrow0\implies \alpha+4\beta-1>0\implies\alpha+4\beta>1$

Hence,option $D$ is correct.

Since,$(2,2)\in S$ but $(2,2)\notin B=\{(\alpha,\beta)\in \mathbb R^2:\alpha>2,\beta>2\}$.Hence,$S\nsubseteq B=\{(\alpha,\beta)\in \mathbb R^2:\alpha>2,\beta>2\}$.
So,option (B) is wrong.

Since,$\alpha+\beta>1,\alpha+4\beta>1\implies (\alpha+\beta)+3\beta>1\implies 3\beta>0\implies \beta>0$,consequently $\alpha>0$.So, $S\subset A$.Hence, option (A) is Correct.

Now,$(-3,4)\in S$,but $(-3,4)\notin A$,then how can $S\subset A?$.

What is wrong with the last proof?

Comment: Probably doesn't answer your question completely, but for your option D argument, the denominator $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ should have become $\sqrt{x^2 + (x^4)^2}$, right?

Comment: Not set theory. Not elementary set theory. Maybe the problem is you don't even know what type if math you are doing?

Comment: @VTand:thank you,i edited it

Comment: I don't understand why $\alpha+\beta+3\beta>1\land \alpha+\beta>1$ should imply $3\beta>0$. If anything, the fact that $\alpha+\beta>1$ should allow for some small negative number to be added without the sum becoming $\le 1$. Like $\alpha =5$, $\beta=-10^{-5}$.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio:Got it, i did mistake

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio:What is the correct proof for $S\subset A?$

Comment: I would say that $S\nsubseteq A$.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio:Can you give an example?

Comment: $\lim_{(x,y)\to 0}\frac{x^9y^0}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ looks pretty $0$ to me.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio:thanks a lot